# Application configuration in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, configuration

I need to have some application settings in my Silverlight project. In a standard .NET project it is accomplished by adding some Settings file. However it is not supported in SL. What should be done then? I think of some xml configuration file, but where should it be placed and how should it be accessed?

What is the most elegant way to set up some application configuration in SL?

Thank you in advance for replies and hints!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you want each site to which the Xap may be deployed to be able to parameterise various aspects of the applications operation then and XML file is probably the best medium.

Use the WebClient to download it, wait for the download to complete before continuing with start code such as constructing and assigning the `RootVisual`.

Comment: I rather think of parametrizing the compilation (as could be done using Settings in standard .net app).

Comment: @Jamie:  The "Settings" in standard .NET have little to do with Compilation.  The function of "Settings" is pretty much what I've described above, a means to provide parameterisations of an application __outside__ of its compiled unit.  The *.exe.config bit of the application.  If thats what you want to acheive then the above is a way to do that.  If not can you modify your question to clarify what it is you want to do, perhaps add a usage scenario.